# Can my MacbookAir run Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, 32-bit, macbook-air

I want to run Windows 8 on my MacbookAir. But I'm pretty bad with computers and everything so I can't really figure out if I need the 32 or 64 bit version of Windows 8?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure every computer built past 2007 can handle x64. If you have at least 4 GB of RAM then you absolutely need x64 to support all that memory.

Comment: So you already know it can run Windows? (Which indeed is true.) Then the title of your question is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your Macbook Air could run windows 8
There are 2 ways in which you could go about achieving this

1)Use a visualization software like virtualbox(free) or parallels(paid but integrates better with OSX) to run windows within OSX like another program
(Both 32 bit or 64 bit can be installed this way)

2)Use bootcamp to install and run windows 8 alongside OSX (dual boot) such that you can select it when starting up
(Windows "8" can only be "Bootcamped" on 2011 MBAs and later)
(Only 64bit Win8 can be installed this way)